# I want to show when check box is checked or status is 1 show checked react js

Tags: reactjs

I want this scenario when check box status is 1 show checked else false. But in my case when I refresh page it shows checked or when check box status is update show checked without page refresh. How it is possible? Please guide me.

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
const handleChange = event => {
      setChecked(!checked)
      const status = event.target.checked?'1':'0'
          
         console.log("status",status)
         const headers = {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
         const task_id = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
         console.log("taskkkkkk",task_id)
    
         let formData = new FormData()
         formData.append('status', status)
         formData.append('task_id', task_id)
       
         api.post('task-updated', formData,{headers: headers })
         .then((response) => {
         
            if (response.data.status == '1') {
               toast.success("Task Updated Successfully");
   
            }
            else {
               console.log(response.data);
            }
      });
   }
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChange} name="status" value={items1._id}  id={items1.status} data-id={items1._id} checked={items1.status== '1'? true:''} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but since you have a controlled input, you should use `checked={checked}` to rely on the state.

And then instead of giving `checked` a default value of `false`, you should do the following:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(items1.status == '1' ? true : false)
```

And now your state is matching the value of the condition `items1.status == '1'` and so you should adapt your code to it.

Also, if you need to execute something whenever the value of your state changes, you should use the `useEffect` hook.

More on the hook here: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp